# Zoom a picture?

Tags: php, gd

```
//Get current dimensions
$width = imagesx($myimage);
$height = imagesy($myimage);

$width = $width * ($zoom/100);
$height = $height * ($zoom/100);

$scale = min($new_width/$width, $new_height/$height);

$new_width = ceil($scale * $width);
$new_height = ceil($scale * $height);




    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $myimage, 0, 0, $offset_x * -1, $offset_y * -1, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

I am trying to Zoom a picture, however in fact it becomes smaller and not zoomed at all. The zoom is a factor like 113/100 = 1.13 It should be 13% zoomed in.

Comment: Why are you calculating a scale? Zooming both dimensions by the same ratio should maintain the aspect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is:

```
//Get current dimensions
$width = imagesx($myimage);
$height = imagesy($myimage);

$new_width = $width * $zoom / 100; //120 zoom will increase the image by 20%
$new_height = $height * $zoom / 100;

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $myimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

actually the first example on php.net is a zoom example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php